# why is my watch:sass command not working?

Tags: reactjs, sass, package.json

I am trying to get sass/scss working with react so i added a few commands to the package.json to get the auto compiling:

```
"scripts": {
  "watch:sass": "sass  --no-source-map --watch src/sass:src/css",
  "build:sass": "sass  --no-source-map src/sass:src/css",
  "start:react": "react-scripts start",
  "build:react": "react-scripts build",
  "start": "npm run start:react && npm run watch:sass",
  "build": "npm run build:react && npm run build:sass",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

and when i do

```
npm start
```

it gives no error but doesnt update the css

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you using create-react-app ?

Comment: @yousoumar My scss is working fine, the styling is getting added, but the auto compile isnt, i want it so that i save my file and the other css file works, and also yes, i am using `npx create-react-app`

Comment: I  see, did you read the response given for the question in that link I posted ? It should solve your problem. You don't need even to change the scripts.